# Mac OS Shell: Find a file by exact modified date time

Tags: macos, shell

I am trying to manage files created by my camera.

I got 2 folders one for `RawFiles` and another for Proxy files.

I want to loop through all the files in RawFiles folder, get the modified date and find the matching file with the same modified date.

I have the following script so far (you may need to change the file path)

I couldn't find a better way to "find" a file that matches an exact time stamp. I've commented out the line that's supposed to find the file matching the timestamp.

I'd like to keep this working on MacOS terminal without any dependency on perl etc.

````
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start Renaming Proxy files matching RAW files."

fmt='%Y%m%d%H%M%S'

RAWFILES=("/Volumes/RAWCard/"*.CRM)

PROXYDIR="/Volumes/ProxyCard/DCIM"

for f in "${RAWFILES[@]}"
do

 echo  "${f}";

 export STAMP="$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "$fmt" "$f")"

 echo "${STAMP}"

 echo "1"

# find $PROXYDIR -type f -newermt "${STAMP}" ! -newermt "${STAMP}"

 echo "Parse"

 date -j -f %s -v +1S "${STAMP}" +"$fmt"

done```
````

Comment: not sure what your Q is. If you're asking for code Review, you should use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask a moderator to move it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com . The `find` looks reasonable. If you're getting errors with it, then post more details so people can replicate your problem. Good luck.

Comment: What is *"ProxyCard"* please? What are you actually trying to do? How can a file be newer than and also not newer than something? Why do you think the dates/times will match to the second? What do you actually want to do when you find a match? Why do print "1" for no apparent reason?

Comment: ProxyCard is just another folder. I basically have 2 folders. I have files in 2 different folders with matching creation dates but with different file names. Hope that makes sense. I am trying to create a script that renames the files in the Proxy folder by matching the creation date. I'll try to update the question.

Comment: Shellter, the "find" statement doesn't return the actual file with the matching creation date. It only works with a range and I'm not sure if I need to add -1 second to the first newermt and +1 to the second newermt to get a range. But is there another way to just compare the dates instead of finding within a range?

Comment: I'm not able to edit the question. So to be clear, there are 2 folders. RAW and PROXY. RAW folder has files 1.CRM, 2.CRM, 3.CRM etc. PROXY has a.mp4, b.mp4, c.mp4 etc. 1.CRM and a.mp4 are created at the same time, 2.CRM and b.mp4 created at the same time (accurate to the second, filenames are more complicated in reality) I want to loop through RAW folder get the created timestamp from 1.CRM and find the file in PROXY folder that matches that creation date to get a.mp4 in this example. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not certain I understand what you are up to, but this should help. You can use `stat` to get the modification (or access, change or birth time) in seconds since 1st January 1970 (epoch) of a whole bunch of files in one go like this:

```
stat -f "%m %SN" RAWCard/*
```

**Sample Output**

```
1511359473 RAWCard/step1.png
1511359474 RAWCard/step2.png
1512638778 RAWCard/step3.png
```

If you do that for both directories, you can then use `join` to join lines on the common field (the time):

```
stat -f "%m %SN" RAWCard/*    > raw
stat -f "%m %SN" ProxyCard/*  > proxy
join raw proxy
```

**Sample Output**

```
1511359473 RAWCard/step1.png ProxyCard/step1.png 
1511359474 RAWCard/step2.png ProxyCard/step2.png
1512638778 RAWCard/step3.png ProxyCard/step3.png
```

Or, you can do it all in one go:

```
join <(stat -f "%m %SN" RAWCard/*) <(stat -f "%m %SN" ProxyCard/*)
```

If you want to then remove the timestamp field, you can do:

```
join -o 1.2,2.2 ...
```

You can also read the pairs in a loop:

```
join -o 1.2,2.2 ... | while read a b ; do
   echo $a is friends with $b
done
```

May I suggest you always carefully check the resulting number of files is correct - since you will have problems if you have two images shot in the same second, or no matching image shot in the same second.

Working Script --

```
echo "Start Renaming Files"

RAWFILES="/Volumes/RAWCard/CRM/REEL_002/*"

PROXYDIR="/Volumes/ProxyCard/DCIM/136_1205/*.MP4"

stat -f "%m %SN" /Volumes/RAWCard/CRM/REEL_002/*.CRM > raw
stat -f "%m %SN" /Volumes/ProxyCard/DCIM/136_1205/*.MP4 > proxy

join raw proxy

join -o 1.2,2.2 raw proxy | while read a b; do
   echo $a is friends with $b
   rawfilebasename=$(basename "$a")
   rawfilename="${rawfilebasename%.*}"
   echo $rawfilename
   proxydirname=$(dirname "$b")
   proxyfilename=$(basename "$b")
   proxyextension="${proxyfilename##*.}"
   echo $proxydirname/$rawfilename.$proxyextension
   mv $b $proxydirname/$rawfilename.$proxyextension

done
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to find one file in ProxyCard folder that has the creation date = 1511359473? I need to rename that matching ProxyCard file. If there a way to loop through this joined the set of lines I guess we can do some kind of string parsing to get the file paths I need to rename.

Comment: You can do this `stat -f "%m %SN" ProxyCard/* | awk '/1511359473/{print $2}'`

Comment: It's a video camera and every video will be at least 1 second long. So all the files will have a different timestamp separated by a second at least

Comment: Or with a variable `stat -f "%m %SN" ProxyCard/* | awk -v t= 1511359473 '$1~t{print $2}'`

Comment: OK, I think I am getting somewhere. Seeing the light in the tunnel... working on the script now.

Comment: I have added an example of a loop to parse the pairs.